# Compiler is forcing me to Implement a finalizer or destructor on '...'

Tags: c#, destructor, dispose, finalizer

when analyzing code in VS 2017, an error telling "Implement a finalizer or destructor on '...'" is displayed. The question is Why?

If I implement the destructor this way:

```
~RawPrinterHelper()
{

}
```

This other message is shown:

```
'RawPrinterHelper' implements a finalizer that only calls conditionally emitted methods or the base type finalizer. Remove the finalizer or ensure that it is only conditionally compiled into the assembly. If this violation occurs against a finalizer that is entirely wrapped in a conditionally-emitted block of code, suppress this message.
```

How to solve this? The class also implements IDisposable interface.

EDIT:

This is the resulting full class:

```
public sealed class RawPrinterHelper : IDisposable
{
    private NativeMethods.DOCINFOA _di = new NativeMethods.DOCINFOA();
    private IntPtr _hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;

    public bool PrinterIsOpened { get; private set; }

    public bool OpenPrinter(string printerName)
    {
        if (!this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            if (NativeMethods.OpenPrinter(printerName, out _hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
                this.PrinterIsOpened = true;
        }

        return this.PrinterIsOpened;
    }

    public void ClosePrinter()
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            NativeMethods.ClosePrinter(_hPrinter);

            this.PrinterIsOpened = false;
        }
    }

    public bool CreateDocument(string name)
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            _di.pDocName = name;
            _di.pDataType = "RAW";
            if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(_hPrinter, 1, _di))
            {
                if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(_hPrinter))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void CloseDocument()
    {
        NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(_hPrinter);
        NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(_hPrinter);
    }

    public bool SendStringToPrinter(string text)
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {

            IntPtr pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(text);
            int dwCount = text.Length;
            int dwWritten = 0;

            try
            {
                return NativeMethods.WritePrinter(_hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool SendBytesToPrinter(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pBytes, bytes.Length);
            int dwCount = bytes.Length;
            int dwWritten = 0;

            try
            {
                return NativeMethods.WritePrinter(_hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBytes);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public byte[] ReceiveBytesFromPrinter()
    {
        if (this.PrinterIsOpened)
        {
            int maxRead = 256;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            IntPtr pBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);

            int nBytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //Read Data                
                if (NativeMethods.ReadPrinter(_hPrinter, pBytes, maxRead, out nBytesRead))
                    return bytes;
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBytes);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        NativeMethods.DOCINFOA di = new NativeMethods.DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "RAW Document";
        // Win7
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Win8+
        // di.pDataType = "XPS_PASS";

        // Open the printer.
        if (NativeMethods.OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = NativeMethods.WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            NativeMethods.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        fs.Close();
        fs = null;
        return bSuccess;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }

    ~RawPrinterHelper()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It just basically says that your destructor does nothing special and is redundant. So either call `Dispose(true)` in your destructor or remove it

Comment: If your class was implemented IDisposable just override Dispose method to write your own destruction logic and garbage collection will do the rest. doesn't need destruction method itself!

Comment: does the type `RawPrinterHelper` have any really unusual field types? unmanaged pointers etc? it is *incredibly* rare that you need to implement a finalizer, so I would only expect to see that in very specific scenarios; alternatively: does it perhaps *subclass* something that has a finalizer? additional question: what code analysis tool is it that is reporting this? anything specific? often the error code would help us know that ... for example, an RCS### warning code is Roslynator, a CS### warning code is the compiler, etc

Comment: @HùngPhạm `Dispose` / `IDisposable` is largely unrelated to finalizers

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm already know, but he said "The class also implements IDisposable interface", so I told him to change the easy way.

Comment: Can you say why you are writing a class that wraps an intptr directly, instead of extending safehandle? Trying to do that sort of work in user code outside of a safehandle is a worst practice.

Comment: You definitely should split your class in two: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About#skip_the_boring_stuff

Answer (score 0):

The finalizer is needed to dispose unmanaged resources. Usually you need not to implement a finalizer, unless you are holding unmanaged resources.

Your finalizer is empty, and this causes the issue: the finalizer is a particular method and the compiler wants you to do something meaningful and adhering to the specs (i.e. must truly free the unmanaged resources). An empty finalizer is a red flag for the compiler because you might have forgotten to implement it. As we are dealing with resources that cannot be automatically freed, the compiler is extra-safe in this case.

If your class implements `IDisposable`, you can implement the `IDisposable` pattern as described here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Comment: I have implemented IDisposable because Code Analysis forced me to do so.... Code Analysis is also forcing me to create a finalizer or a destructor. If I create the destructor and inside it I call Dispose(), Code Analysis is happy, but this is ugly. I have edited the question so that I show the full class... at the end, destructor and finalizer.

Comment: Also Code Analysis forces to add a destructor or finalizer in this class. I have several classes in the project and none of them caused this error. I include the full code of the class so you can see it...maybe this class has something unmanaged that need to be freed in destructor.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes mocking your code, the only interesting analyzer error I have is this: Warning CA1816 'RawPrinterHelper.Dispose()' to call 'GC.SuppressFinalize(object)'. This will prevent unnecessary finalization of the object once it has been disposed and it has fallen out of scope. Is this the error you report?